# How do I keep Windows 10 from installing Office packages?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, bloatware

Windows 10 keeps downloading and placing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office" on my system drive. It consumes 2.5GB.
I am not using MS Office products. I use LibreOffice and Google docs. I deleted this folder once, but it came back within hours. I want this to be never ever being downloaded and installed, what do I need to do?

Comment: Could you open the Microsoft Office folder to check which subfolders are there?? Besides, is there any task related to Office in Task Manager, such as "Microsoft Office Click-to-Run"? If yes, you may try to block this execution program from access Internet in Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Start, Settings and Update.

On the right side, click on Advanced Options.

Uncheck (turn off) "Receive updates for other Microsoft Products"

In Programs and Features, make sure Office (any version) is not installed.

If you have a Microsoft Account, make sure the account does not include an Office subscription. Remove it it if there is Office associated with your Microsoft Account.

That should fix this issue for you.

Comment: This seems to work. If the folder stays gone now I make this the accepted answer.